# Term for an identifier that has been superseded

Tags: data-cleaning

Is there a 'proper' term for an ID (or IDs) that have been superseded by (or merged into) another ID?

My use case:

- rsIDs are used by geneticists to refer to a [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism). These take the form of a string 'rs#####'
- Over time, some of these rsIDs are merged into others when it becomes evident that they refer to the same SNP with another rsID. eg [rs879161658](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs879161658)
- it is useful to keep track of these old identifier(s) that were used, even when using the latest rsID as the canonical identifier. rs879161658 will still be found in some legacy resources
- it is not possible to control the creation or naming of these rsIDs

I've considered AKA, alias, and even Née (born as) but is there something traditionally used? I could ask this on a language-focused stackexchange but here seems like it would be more useful